# What fonts are used in this picture?

Tags: font-identification

[image: http://imgur.com/YbN9AI0]

So this is the picture, can someone please tell me what the fonts used in this picture are? 
Thanks
-W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text **Prodigy** is **[Brannboll Fet](http://www.whatfontis.com/Brannboll-Fet-mawns.font?text=Prodigy)** Font.

Text **MC** is **[Evil Dead](http://www.whatfontis.com/Evil-Dead.font?text=MC)** Font.

I have used **[whatfontis.com](http://www.whatfontis.com/)** to detect fonts.